Why does my scanning app freeze on iOS with the SDK update from 49 to 51?
My app is used to scan QRs. The problem is that when updating the SDK version 49 --> 51 and updating packages like expo-camera to version 15, the app freezes when scanning a few QRs.
Application flow:

Select the show: this takes you to the show tab screen
Select the scanning tab
Scan the QR
Go to the Success screen
Tap a button and go back to the previous screen (the scanning screen)

Versions:

expo: 51.0.26
expo-camera: 15.0.14

I tried:

Using the legacy camera
Disabling transitions between screens
Downgrading expo-camera but it doesn't support SDK-51
Downgrading to SDK-50 but I can't use Expo Go for testing


Try using Instruments to profile the code during the hang.  That should show you what it is doing.  Then provide more information based on what you see.  There's no way to even guess with the information here, short of somebody just happening to have run into the exact problem themselves.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
